# Docverter loses utf-8 encoding on markdown -> pdf

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc, pdf-conversion, docverter

When I try to convert an utf-8 encoded markdown file to pdf using Docverter (through the API), I just lose non-ASCII characters.

Any solution to that?

I want to convert .md -> .pdf. Maybe Docverter can help to do .md -> .html, then I could use some other library / service for the .html -> .pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update (14/10/2013)

The problem with boolean options in Docverter [is now solved](https://github.com/Docverter/docverter/issues/17#issuecomment-26221052), so you can now do a direct conversion from `md` to `pdf`, passing the option `ascii=true` to Docverter. This causes the intermediate HTML to use entities instead of utf-8, and thus the resulting pdf is OK.

## Original answer

After a lot of research (I also had this same problem), I discovered that the bug is in the html->pdf conversion made by Docverter, which uses Flying Saucer libraries. This conversion ignores any non-ascii char in the HTML input, even if the charset is correctly set to `utf-8` in the `meta` tags.

However, if the HTML contains entities such as `&#243;` etc, then Flying Saucer does include those characters, and assuming a font which has the correct encoding (default fonts used by the library are fine), the proper char (`ó` in this example) is shown in the resulting pdf.

So I ended up with the following approach:

1. Use Docverter to convert `.md` -> `html`
2. Process the resulting `html` to use HTML entities instead of utf-8
3. Use Docverter again to convert `.html` -> `.pdf`

Step 2 is easy if you happen to use python. In this case, the following lines do the trick:

```py
def fixHTML(filename):
   f = open(filename, "r")
   content = unicode(f.read(), "utf-8")  # Reads the file into a unicode string
   f.close()
   f = open(filename, "w")
   f.write(content.encode("ascii", "xmlcharrrefreplace")) # Writes with the fixed encoding
```

**Note**: This convoluted way should not be required because `pandoc` accepts the switch `--ascii` which forces it to produce HTML as the one obtained in step 2. However, Docverter parser for boolean options [seems to be broken](https://github.com/Docverter/docverter/issues/17), so it is not possible to pass the option `ascii` to Docverter.